# Mount Nas to Ubuntu Server and samba?

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba

I want to mount my NAS drive into my Ubuntu Server so I can reach it from my Windows desktop. So far so good.

This is my Ubuntu server's `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.0.2/Public /DataShare/Aurora-NAS cifs credentials=/etc/samba/SAMBA_SHARE_credentials, 0 0
```

`/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[DataShare]
path = /DataShare/
available = yes
valid users = slaffe
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

I can read and write in `DataShare` (this folder is on my Ubuntu Server), but I cannot write on `/DataShare/Aurora-NAS/`.

Comment: How did you set up your credentials?  Are all users defined everywhere?